# How to pass parameters to Node's Q library's (denodeify) promise handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

In the below code I would like to have variables `a, b, c` to be passed as parameter when `processhttprequest()` gets called.

```
    var q = require("q");
    var request = require('request');

    function myfun()
    {
        var a, b, c;
        //do some work here
        var httprequest = q.denodeify(request);
        var httprequestpromise = httprequest(httpoptions);
        httprequestpromise.then(processhttprequest);
    }
```

I tried `httprequestpromise.then(processhttprequest.bind([a, b, c]));` but no luck. Is this supported by Q, or any other promise library.

Comment: The first argument to `bind` is whatever `this` you would like the function to use. [Check out the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Do not pass an array.

Comment: But my question is not about how `bind` method works in javascript, but more about how promise works in Q library of node. Btw- `bind` that was just a long shot that I tried.

Comment: You don't need to use `bind`, but if you correct your usage of it, I think your code will work as you want it to.

Comment: Wow, people are still using Q o_0?

Comment: The cloud platform that I use does not support latest Node to make use the generics. Btw- any other suggested promise libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.bind()` like this:

```
httprequestpromise.then(processhttprequest.bind(null, a, b, c));
```

This creates a dummy function that will add the arguments `a`, `b`, and `c` before calling `processhttprequest()`.

---

Or, you can do it manually with your own stub function like this:

```
function myfun()
{
    var a, b, c;
    //do some work here
    var httprequest = q.denodeify(request);
    var httprequestpromise = httprequest(httpoptions);
    httprequestpromise.then(function(result) {
        return processhttprequest(a, b, c, result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining this. In addition to solving my issue...now, I'm starting to understand the need for  stub function as well. Thanks again!

Comment: A clarification on manual stub function. Does the `result` also gets passed to `processhttprequest()`, or will the `result` be accessible inside `processhttprequest()` through closure?

Comment: @Dan: There's no closure unless you have `processhttprequest` declared inside of the stub callback. You'll need to pass it explicitly as an argument, I've taken the freedom to edit jfriend's answer to show that.

Comment: @Dan - In the `.bind()` example, the arguments `a`, `b` and `c` are in addition to the `result` argument that the `.then()` would add.  `.bind()` prepends these arguments so they come before.  In the second example, you are calling `processhttprequeset()` directly yourself so it gets whatever arguments you pass it.  If you want `result` passed, you can pass it - if you don't need it you don't need to pass it - that is totally up to you.

Answer (score 0):

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) doesn't take an array. Once you fix your usage of `bind`, your code should work as you described.

Try
`httprequestpromise.then(processhttprequest.bind(null, a, b, c));`

or

`httprequestpromise.then(function(){
  processhttprequest(a, b, c);
});`